# Thoughtworks Go Alternatives

Tags: release-management, thoughtworks-go

We were investigating the possibility of using Thoughtworks Go to help improve our Build / Deployment / Release process here at work, but due to the price factor and what you actually got we decided against it.

I was wondering, are there any alternatives to Thoughtworks Go around? They could either be commercial or open source, I don't mind.

Comment: ThoughtWorks just announced that they would be making Go free & open-source. http://www.thoughtworks.com/news/go-continuous-delivery-now-available-as-free-open-source. So may be you can give it a try again.

Answer (score 10):

Go has just been released as open source - see http://www.thoughtworks.com/news/go-continuous-delivery-now-available-as-free-open-source

Comment: It uses in memory H2 database for this. If you need to use a real database, you need to pay for it.

Answer (score 5):

This really depends what you want to achieve.

If you are looking to implement [Continuous Delivery](http://continuousdelivery.com/) and therefore deployment pipelines (from dev all the way to production), then GO is the only tool which has this higher-level view at the moment, I believe.

OTOH, if you;re just looking for a CI server, then the free version of GO works well, as does the free version of TeamCity, Jenkins and Atlassian Bamboo. None of the latter three yet supports the concept of deployment pipelines as a first-class feature, I think.

Comment: TeamCity can do everything GO can do, it just has different names for the same concepts. Using Dependencies (Snapshot/Artifact) you model your pipelines as in GO, they are just the primary focus of TeamCity.

Comment: Technically, it might be true that you can do most things with TeamCity that you can do in Go, but you will find it difficult to represent parallel pipelines effectively in TeamCity, and the speed and ease of setting up a deployment pipeline with role-based security is *still* much quicker in Go than in any other tool I know.

Answer (score 5):

I wasn't able to comment on Matthew's answer, but Inedo's [BuildMaster](http://inedo.com/buildmaster) is a very popular platform to do just this. It has a bit more features than Go, and although it's a commercial product, there is a free version available that's pretty useful for small teams.

(Disclaimer: I work for [Inedo](http://inedo.com), but have experience in both platforms)

Comment: Even though you can't comment yet, this is a valid answer! Thanks for doing it right. =)

Answer (score 3):

I did a thorough review of every Continuous Delivery-oriented product out there, and found that GO was clearly the most well suited for the role. It provides a level of visual modeling for parallel and sequential workflow that no other product can quite match.

At Nordstrom, we are now adopting GO as our recommended Continuous Delivery management server. The only product which truly competes is Jenkins, which most of us find too clunky to be a desirable alternative.

It's now open-source, so you need not worry about licensing costs. I'd suggest going back and telling your cohorts the GO is now the clear open-source leader in this domain.

Answer (score 2):

We had similar conclusions: the free version of Go, the "$499 for annual support on the free version", and the "$499 for 3 remote agents" were worth considering, but the price jump after that (for the "enterprise" version with release management support) was astronomical.

For commercial alternatives, there's Electric Cloud, but it's even more expensive than the ThoughtWorks product.

For Open Source, there's Cruise Control (Go is a re-written private version of the open source Cruise Control), Continuum, LuntBuild, Anthill, etc.  These are mostly continuous integration build systems (i.e. more emphasis placed on running the build than managing the results) but they do seem to work well (I've used Cruise Control and Hudson in the past with much success.)

Answer (score 1):

ThoughtWorks Go is now open source and free - https://github.com/GoCD/GoCD